# Problem with wifi ubuntu 16.04.04 LTE

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

Recently I installed an update to my ubuntu installation, wich have been running smooth for a good month since I first installed it. After the update, I have not been able to connect to the internett by wifi. IT tryes to connect for about a minute, but fails. Ethernet works. I know the wifi-device is functional, as my windows 10 installment on my second harddrive runds fine with wifi.
I have tryed everything I can think of, also everyting I have found at google and askubuntu. Nothing has worked. 
Some info:
Computer: Acer E5 575G
Network card: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164

Drivers are installed.

I also tryed running Linux from the USB drive i installed from, but it could not use the wifi. I formatted the harddrive, and re-installed Ubuntu. Still nothing.

Any advice?

- Sve

Comment: The issue has been resolved.
Slightly embarresing, as I maybe should have thought of it before reinstalling ubuntu 4 times, but i resetted modom/router. WiFi now works. 
Thanks for all help, anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle wifi and bluetooth by pressing [Fn] + [F3]. This will toggle between all off, bluetooth only, wifi only and both enabled. Give a try.

Good luck!

Comment: That´s not the issue. The wifi is on, and is trying to connect (the wifi-signal-symbol is highlighting one part at a time; buffering). 
Anyway, would the wifi-seting to on/off carry through a complete reboot?

Comment: Happy you were able to get wifi working.